# Greatest volume of sphere inscribed in a cone with given Lateral area

Tags: derivatives, volume, maxima-minima

The Lateral area of a right circular cone is $S$. Fine the Greatest volume of Sphere that can be inscribed in it.

My try:

Given that $$\pi rl=S$$

Let the radius of the sphere inscribed in it be $R$

Let the semi vertex angle of cone be $\theta$

We have height of the cone as:

$$h=R+R\csc \theta$$

Now

$$\pi^2 r^2 l^2 =S^2$$ $\implies$

$$\pi^2 r^2 (r^2+h^2)=S^2$$

$$r^2(r^2+R^2(1+\csc \theta)^2)=\frac{S^2}{\pi^2}$$

So:

$$R^2=\frac{\frac{S^2}{\pi^2r^2}-r^2}{(1+\csc \theta)^2}\tag{1}$$

Also:

$$\sin \theta=\frac{r}{l}$$

So

$$\pi r \frac{r}{\sin \theta}=S$$

$\implies$

$$\csc \theta=\frac{S}{\pi r^2}$$

Hence $(1)$ becomes:

$$R^2=\frac{r^2(S^2-r^4\pi^2)}{(\pi r^2+S)^2}$$

$$R^2=r^2\frac{(S-\pi r^2)}{(S+\pi r^2)}$$

$$\pi R^2=\pi r^2\frac{(S-\pi r^2)}{(S+\pi r^2)}$$

Letting $\pi r^2=t$ we get

$$\pi R^2=f(t)=\frac{t(S-t)}{S+t}$$

Differentiating with respect to $t$ we get:

$$f'(t)=-1+\frac{2S^2}{(S+t)^2}=0$$ $\implies$

$$t=\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)S$$

Hence

$$\pi r^2=\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)S$$

$$r^2=\frac{\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)S}{\pi}$$

So we get:

$$R^2=\frac{(3-2\sqrt{2})S}{\pi}$$

Hence Maximum volume of sphere is:

$$V=\frac{4\pi R^3}{3}=0.0534 (S)^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

But i feel this approach is tedious.Any better method?

Comment: I feel that you have used the optimization tag incorrectly. Please take a look.

Comment: I find that your solution for $R$ is not in agreement for the inscribed circle in an isosceles triangle, namely. $R=r(l-r)/\sqrt(l^2-r^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

The relation that you you desire for the radius of the incircle can found by examining the figure below. If $\theta$ is the half angle of the vertex, then clearly

$$
\sin\theta=\frac{r}{l}=\frac{R}{h-R}\\
h=\sqrt{l^2-r^2}
$$

From here you can find

$$R=\frac{rh}{l+r}=\frac{r\sqrt{l^2-r^2}}{l+r}=r\sqrt{\frac{l-r}{l+r}}$$

I believe this is what you are looking for.[image: Isosceles triangle and incircle]